# ElasticSearch Java API get array inside document and apply filter and sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, elasticsearch

I have to write a complex query, using Java ES API, which will retrieve a page of result, sorted and optionnally filtered. So far here is what my mapping in ElasticSearch looks like :

```
{
    "mappings" : {
      "applications" : {
        "properties" : {
          "applications" : {
            "properties" : {
              "dynamicSize" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "packageName" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "type" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "updateTimestamp" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "version" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "imei" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "type" : "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically, I have a document containing an IMEI (the key to get the document(s)), a timestamp and an applications list. I want to get application lists, for the most recent **timestamp** of the document based on an **imei**. It is hard for me to see how I can write this query. In Java, I've already done this :

```
SortBuilder sortBuilder = SortBuilders.fieldSort(pageParameter.getOrderField()).order(pageParameter.getOrder());
SearchHit[] hitsArray = client.prepareSearch(index)
                .setTypes(type)
                .setQuery(termQueryBuilder)
                .setFrom(pageParameter.getFrom())
                .setSize(pageParameter.getSize())
                .setPostFilter(pageParameter.getFilters())
                .addSort(sortBuilder)
                .execute()
                .actionGet()
                .getHits()
                .getHits();
```

Where pageParameter object contains the **current page** to retrieve (ex : 0 (page 1)), the **size** of the page (ex: 25), the **sortOrder** and a JSONObject of the optionnal **filters**.

**The issues here :**

1- The problem is that I get my document based on the IMEI, but the sort order won't works as it does not look for a field contained into the "applications" array.

I tried in sort order to put **applications.name** , asc like this :

```
SortBuilder sortBuilder = SortBuilders.fieldSort("applications." + pageParameter.getOrderField()).order(pageParameter.getOrder());
```

I also added after **setType()** the method **.addField("applications")** because I though it would retrieve me the list, and then I could apply on this my pagination and sorting/filtering process.
In debug, I see it's all ok the sortBuilder contains "**applications.name**" as field to sort by, and "**asc**" as order

2- And if I get multiple identical IMEI's, I will do this for every document, but I want only the latest.

If someone knows well this API, can you please help me ?
Thanks !

**EDIT :**

I tried to do so with at first, a REST request in order to check if this is feasable. At the moment I didn't get the applications list sorted, filtered and paged from the wanted IMEI.

I applied the following mapping :

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "applications": {
            "properties": {
                "imei": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "applications": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "dynamicSize": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "packageName": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "type": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "version": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "updateTimestamp": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "timestamp": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this, I tried different queries, like these ones :

**TEST 1 :**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "imei": "359678064430535"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
      "nested": {
          "path": "applications",
          "filter": {
              "term": {
                  "name" :"SoundAlive"
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "sort": [{
      "applications.name" : { "order" : "asc" }
  }],
  "inner_hits": {},
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5
}
```

**TEST 2 :**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "applications.imei": "359678064430535"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [
    {
      "applications.name": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested_path": "applications"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

**TEST3 :**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "imei": "359678064430535"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [{
      "applications.name" : { "order" : "asc" }
  }],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 2,
  "fields": [ "applications.name" ]
}
```

In the TEST 3, I'm able to retrieve all the applications.name from the array contained in object, but I can't retrieve the whole object array, nor filter or sort on it :(

**EDIT 2 :**

I tried another query today:

```
{
  "query": {
     "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match": { 
              "imei" : "359678064430535"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "applications",
                "query" : {
                    "match_all": { }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "and": [{
                        "term": {
                            "applications.name" : "myAppName"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

But I can't sort on a nested query, and the results seems to be insensitive. also I still get the complete object back, not only the application list ... Why is this so hard ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: I will try to help you with you problems one by one, if not resolved already.
If you need only applications in source, use 'fields' and specify what fields you need in response source.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-request-fields.html
Also, let me know the elastic version you are using for precise help.

Comment: Hi Prashant, I've rollbacked to the previous way; as I didnt succeed to make a working query, retrieving an application list, sorted, filtered and paged. I did it before in Java, and wanted to switch to a single query, which seemed to be more clear and more optimized. But I gave up as I saw how much time I wasted on that.

Comment: I'm using Elasticsearch 2.4 now (when I tried I was on 2.2) and yes, I'm only interested in the query by the array of applications contained in the document type "applications"